# What is a "De-clicked" aperture control ring?

Tags: lens, aperture, terminology, samyang

The [Samyang 85mm T1.5 Cine Lens](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/895592-REG/Samyang_sycv85c_85mm_T1_5_Cine_AS.html) featured a "De-clicked" aperture control ring.  What exactly is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means the aperture ring does not have detents or, if it does, there are no audible clicks.

This is intended for video shooting as it does not make any noise when turning the aperture ring. Depending on how the lens is designed, the aperture may be stepped or not. If it is not stepped, it usual says *continuous aperture* or something similar.

Comment: This answer is good, so I won't make my own, but I'll add a few less-essential points: many (probably most) lenses with de-clicked aperture rings also have rings modified for use with follow-focus systems (notice the large "teeth" on the rings of the Samyang). This allows better use on a camera rig, and more specifically enables the operator to adjust exposure while shooting without jarring, inconsistent stops during the movement. Some lenses can be de-clicked by the consumer (I have a Samyang 35mm that is home-de-clicked) but I wouldn't recommend the procedure to most people.

Comment: Thanks! What are describing is *geared focus-ring* IIRC and that is answer for another question :) It is possible to have one without the other.

Comment: You're right, you absolutely can have one without the other. In the case of this lens and virtually every other cinema-centric lens, however, both modifications are applied. It's pretty rare, I think, to see a lens manufactured with one of these modifications but not the other.